# gsuite domains with email scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-workspace

> http://midbrainactivation.org/nikka/index.php?domain=apkios.co

Can anyone check the link above and tell me how exactly this is done?

To me, the domain is subscribed with google g-suits and then emails are created. But I want to know what is this script or how can I do the same with my own domain.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

They are using G Suite Directory API in the back end. When you put your name, it just creates an account on their domain.
I have created a similar application for a University where students authorize with pres hared details and once they input valid details, their account is created on the university G Suite domain.
https://sites.google.com/a/kdis.ac.kr/gmail-for-kdis/

Comment: Many thanks Waqar Ahmed. I'm not a programmer but I hope I can try to implement this. Is there anything necessary from your point of view regarding anything extra I should know or be aware of keeping in consideration that I'm a non-programmer but want to develop the exact thing? Thanks.